# How do I reproduce exactly and add the current symbol I in these RL and RC Circuitz? MWEs attached

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

This is the MWE for the first diagram:

```
\begin {document}{standalone}
\usepackage[straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [short] ++(0,1) node [right] {$-$}
    to [open, v^>=$E$, o-o] ++(0,1) node [right] {$+$}
    to [short] ++(0,1)
    to [R=$R$, i>^=$I$, resistors/zigs=6] ++(4,0)
    to [cute inductor, l_=$L$, mirror] ++(0,-3)
    to [] ++(-4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end {document}
```

I want the inductor to appear as displayed in the first diagram and not inverted the way the MWE code displays after typesetting. I also want the current symbol I to appear as in the first diagram.

This is the MWE for the second diagram:

```
\begin {document}{standalone}
\usepackage[straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [short] ++(0,1) node [right] {$-$}
    to [open, v^>=$E(t)$, o-o] ++(0,1) node [right] {$+$}
    to [short] ++(0,1)
    to [R=$R$, resistors/zigs=6] ++(4,0)
    to [curved capacitor, l_=$C$, capacitors/thickness=7] ++(0,-3)
    to [ i>^=$I$] ++(-4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end {document}
```

I want the capacitor C to be placed outside as in the second diagram and not inside as in the MWE display. I also want the current symbol I to appear as in the second diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have strange MWEs --- the `\begin{document}{standalone}` does not compile and break everything... fixing that, then, for the fist circuit:

1. if you do not want the inductor `mirror`ed, just remove `mirror`;
2. the position of the label is controlled by the `^` or `_` after the `l`; in this case the default one serves you;
3. if you want the current marked on the short circuit below, add it to the short circuit, not to the resistor.

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.72mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [short] ++(0,1) node [right] {$-$}
    to [open, v^>=$E$, o-o] ++(0,1) node [right] {$+$}
    to [short] ++(0,1)
    to [R=$R$, resistors/zigs=6] ++(4,0)
    to [cute inductor, l=$L$] ++(0,-3)
    to [short, i_=$I$] ++(-4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end {document}
```

[image: compiled circuit form the code above]

If you also want to fix the position of the *E* arrow, you can, too --- look around page 199 in the manual:

[image]

(and clearly change the positions of the signs, although now they are not aligned with the arrow. If you want that, maybe you need some sort of [advanced voltage positioning](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#f0))

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.72mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{open voltage position=legacy}
    \draw (0,0) to [short] ++(0,1) node [left] {$-$}
    to [open, v^>=$E$, o-o] ++(0,1) node [left] {$+$}
    to [short] ++(0,1)
    to [R=$R$, resistors/zigs=6] ++(4,0)
    to [cute inductor, l=$L$] ++(0,-3)
    to [short, i_=$I$] ++(-4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end {document}
```

[image]

I think you can easily find the changes needed in the second diagram now.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very detailed and solves all my questions, including the positioning of E, which I forgot to ask (lol). I appreciate.